# Crediting a Star Alliance codeshare flight to a third partner airline FF program

Tags: loyalty-programs, star-alliance, code-share

What mileage table is used in the case where there is a codeshare flight marketed by Airline 1, operated by Airline 2, but where the miles are credited to Airline 3 - if they were all part of Star Alliance?

For example, a flight in K class from EWR-FRA marketed (and ticketed) by Lufthansa but operated by United, crediting to Asiana.

Asiana gives 0% for Lufthansa K class, but at least 50% for any United class. So would this flight earn 0% or 50% with Asiana?

Answer (score 4):

The [Asiana frequent flyer membership guide](https://m.flyasiana.com/C/KR/KO/common/file/download-static-file/files/club/membership_system/member_information/membership_system_subscription/EN/pdf/ACguide_en) says on page 31:

> 3. When a member boards a codeshare flight, the member earns miles according to the fare and the class of the ticket purchased and the mileage program of the **airline operating the flight**.
>
> (...)
>
> When a member boards a codeshare flight, the member earns miles according to the fare and the class of the ticket purchased and the mileage earning program of the operating carrier.
> e.g. When a member boards an OZ/UA codeshare flight operated by OZ (Q Class, US route): Miles are earned for V Class of OZ, which is the operator of the flight.